# CentOS 7 Kickstart Partition Config

Tags: centos

I have a network automated Kickstart install for CentOS 7 setup, but the partitioning section of the anaconda.cfg is not working as expected. This is what the section looks like. The install hangs at the GUI screen, complains "Kickstart insufficient" on the disk.

```
# Disk partitioning information
zerombr
clearpart --initlabel --all
part /boot --ondisk=sda --fstype ext4 --size=512 --asprimary
part pv.3 --size=1 --grow --ondisk=sda
volgroup vg01 pv.3
logvol / --fstype ext4 --name=root_lv --vgname=vg01 --size=102400
logvol /var --fstype ext4 --name=var_lv --vgname=vg01 --size=1 --grow
logvol swap --fstype swap --name=swap_lv --vgname=vg01 --recommended
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I put an extra 0 for root. It was bigger than sda had space for.